# I can't deal with a certain type of determinants problems

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-decomposition

**Prove that, without expanding**

[image: Prove that]

[image: Prove that]

How should my thinking start about these problems? how can I prove that the product of two variables equals square of the third?

Comment: For problems like these it's better to explicitly write the determinant out on both sides and show equality.

Comment: Sadly I have to only use properties without expanding

Comment: @YoussefWalid Do you already know that $\;\det A=\det A^t\;$ ?

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @Vincent my guess is that they want the asker to show more of his own work.  In any case, it seems they cared enough to downvote, but not enough to explain their objections.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1\\
a&b&c\\
bc&ac&ba
\end{vmatrix} =
\frac 1{abc} \begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1\\
a&b&c\\
1/a&1/b&1/c
\end{vmatrix} = 
\frac 1{bc} \begin{vmatrix}
a&1&1\\
a^2&b&c\\
1&1/b&1/c
\end{vmatrix} =\\
\frac 1{c} \begin{vmatrix}
a&b&1\\
a^2&b^2&c\\
1&1&1/c
\end{vmatrix} = 
\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&c\\
a^2&b^2&c^2\\
1&1&1
\end{vmatrix} =\\
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1\\
a&b&c\\
a^2&b^2&c^2\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
and from here, it's enough to note that $|A| = |A^T|$.  If we want to phrase this in terms of matrix multiplication, this amounts to the observation that
$$
\pmatrix{0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0}
\pmatrix{1\\&1\\&&\frac{1}{abc}}\pmatrix{1&1&1\\a&b&c\\bc&ac&ab}
\pmatrix{a\\&b\\&&c} = 
\pmatrix{1&1&1\\
a&b&c\\
a^2&b^2&c^2}
$$

Try to apply a similar trick to the second question.  For the first three steps, note that
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
bc&a^2&a^2\\
b^2&ac&b^2\\
c^2&c^2&ab
\end{vmatrix} = 
\frac{1}{abc}
\begin{vmatrix}
bc/a & a & a\\
b & ac/b & b\\
c & c & ab/c
\end{vmatrix}
$$